# Send value from one button to another button express-handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I am showing some dynamic value on a table. in the table each row have a delete button( Suppose Button A ). If click the delete button ( Button A ) open a modal to confirm delete and there have confirm button( Button B ). From confirm button I am calling the api to delete the entity with the entity id.

Now I have the id on Button A and I am sending the request from button B. How can I sent the id from Button A to Button B.

Button A:

```
<td>
    <button data-toggle="modal" value =  {{this.id}} data-target="#myModal">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

Modal With button B:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            Are you sure you want to delete the entry?
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="/admin/dashbord/category/[id will be here ]/delete" class="btn btn-danger">yes</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

I have given the `{{this.id}} on the url` of button B but it is always deleting the `top or last` element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class (example .delete) to the button,

```
<button data-toggle="modal" value ={{this.id}} class="delete" data-target="#myModal">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">delete</i>
    </button>
```

then add a class to the confirmation link (example .yes):

```
<a href="/admin/dashbord/category/[id will be here ]/delete" class="btn btn-danger yes">yes</a>
```

then get onclick event on the button and get the value of the button and insert it in the href attribut :

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function () {
     var value = $(this).val();
  console.log("value : ", $(this).val())

   $(".modal-dialog .yes").attr("href","/admin/dashbord/category/"+value+"/delete");
});
```

see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRmxwr)

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know is that working for me or not after test .